# set circle size and label size on venn diagram with matplotlib-venn

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-venn

I have a couple of different Venn diagrams created with matplotlib-venn library, which share at least one set. I would like the circle of that set to be of the same size on both, so they are comparable. I would also like to change the size of the font of the labels, but I don't understand yet how to get that from the matplotlib-venn functions. How could I do it?

an example of the sets could be something like this:

```
from matplotlib_venn import venn3

s1=set('abracadabra')
s2=set('alakazam')
s3=set('stackoverflow')
s4=set('hocus pocus')
v_test1=venn3([s1,s2,s3],('set1','set2','set3'))
v_test1=venn3([s1,s3,s4],('set1','set3','set4'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `venn3` function it call `solve_venn3_circles` to calculate centers and radius of circles. It is mean that you can not set radius by yourself because it is affect the final image and it may be incorrect. However you may try to adjust your circles' size by `normalize_to` argument of `venn3` function.

For font size you can use this code:

```
for t in v_test1.set_labels: t.set_fontsize(22)
for t in v_test1.subset_labels: t.set_fontsize(20)
```

Or set font size by  id:

```
label = v_test1.get_label_by_id('111')          
label.set_fontsize(22)
```

For id information look for [manual page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib-venn).

Comment: thanks! it worked, although my labels got completely cropped when I saved it using `plt.savefig()`, even worse if I use `plt.tight_layout()` first